# A 4th-order linear PDE

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, differential-operators

I am interested in the following type of $4$-th order linear PDE with $2$ variables (i.e., $x$ and $t$):

**$x^3 f_{xxxt}+ f =0$**

Does anyone know if this type of PDE already appeared in the literature? It looks quite simple.

P.S.
To clarify: the $f$-equation is a simplified equation based on a longer "$P$-equation" via a change of variable: $f =(x^2 t) P$ with a boundary condition $P(x,t=0)=1$. This BC rules out many solutions/ansatzes. This $4$th-order PDE can be solved, e.g., perturbatively in a small $t$ expansion, but I wonder how to approach this equation more generally, from (say) a geometric viewpoint.

Comment: Do you have any boundary conditions?

Comment: I am not very sure about all the boundary conditions so I am just wondering if this type of simple linear PDE might be already discussed in the math literature. (But if I Iet $f(x,t)= x^2 t P(x,t)$, I would like to impose (at least) that $P(x,0)=1$.)

Comment: Why the [tag:projective-geometry] tag? I would have thought [tag:reference-request] might be better in its place, if it's possible to drop. And why [tag:stochastic-differential-equations]?

Comment: The substitution $x=e^y$ transforms this to a constant coefficient problem. This makes available the machinery of Fourier and Laplace transforms. What to do further really depends on what you want to know about the PDE.

Comment: A two-parameter family of solutions is $f=Cx^a \exp [-t/(a(a-1)(a-2))]$ ...

Comment: The f-equation is a simplified equation based on a P-equation via $f(,)=^2  (,)$ with a BC $(,0) = 1$. This simple BC rules out many ansatzes.

Comment: If $f$ is a solution then so is $-x^2f(x^{-1},-t)$.